# Counting Rows but keeping duplicate values as the same count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Using SQL Server 2016.

I've been stuck on a SQL problem for a week and decided to break the problem down into sections. I solved one section but having issues with this. My data set is large but a sample of it would be

```
    state | duration | time
    ------+----------+--------------------------
      1   | 28.29    | 2017-08-09 00:00:22.460
      1   | 10.05    | 2017-08-09 00:00:50.753    
      2   |  9.47    | 2017-08-09 00:01:00.797    
      3   |  8.80    | 2017-08-09 00:01:10.270
      1   | 15.79    | 2017-08-09 00:01:19.073 
      1   | 28.51    | 2017-08-09 00:01:34.860
```

The result table will have one more column that is called group_counter and will look like the table below. I've searched and found some code that uses COUNT with a PARTITION BY and GROUP BY. but the result is not correct as it does not keep the same count value for duplicates that occur one after the other. The data is already ordered in the way that I want. Any help would be much appreciated at this point.

```
  state | duration | time                    | group_counter
  ------+----------+-------------------------+--------------
    1   | 28.29    | 2017-08-09 00:00:22.460 |      1
    1   | 10.05    | 2017-08-09 00:00:50.753 |      1   
    2   |  9.47    | 2017-08-09 00:01:00.797 |      2  
    3   |  8.80    | 2017-08-09 00:01:10.270 |      3
    1   | 15.79    | 2017-08-09 00:01:19.073 |      4
    1   | 28.51    | 2017-08-09 00:01:34.860 |      4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `lag` window function to denote row where state change in the increasing order of time and then use cumulative sum to generate your group counter.

```
select t.*,
    sum(flag) over (order by time) as group_counter
from (
    select t.*,
        case when state = lag(state) over (order by time) 
            then 0 else 1 
        end as flag
    from your_table t
    ) t;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Had to make tweaks but the result is what i want.